# Angular 5 ngrx Effect no exported member 'ofType'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am trying to implement Effects for my ngrx state manager. Currently I am using `Angular v5.2.1`, `ngrx v4.1.1` and `rxjs v5.5.6`. 
I tried "older" proach for example

```
@Effect() login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.ofType('LOGIN')
.mergeMap(action =>
  this.http.post('/auth', action.payload)
    // If successful, dispatch success action with result
    .map(data => ({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: data }))
    // If request fails, dispatch failed action
    .catch(() => of({ type: 'LOGIN_FAILED' }))
);
```

But I was getting an error  `Property 'mergeMap' does not exist on type 'Actions<Action>'`. 
So I used new `pipe` method. The problem is when I try to import `ofType` operator

```
// ...
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Effect, Actions, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';

import { map, mergeMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class WifiEffects {

  @Effect()
  getWifiData: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(WifiTypes.getWifiNetworks),
    mergeMap((action: GetWifiNetworks) =>
      this.mapService.getWifiNetworks().pipe(
        map((data: WifiNetworks) => new GetWifiNetworksSucc(data)),
        catchError(() => of(new GetWifiNetworksErr()))
      )),
  );

  constructor (
    private actions$: Actions,
    private mapService: GoogleMapDataService
  ) {}

}
```

Iam getting an error `Module '".../node_modules/@ngrx/effects/effects"' has no exported member 'ofType'.` Any ideas?

Comment: Have you `npm install @ngrx/effects --save`? If you already have it, try just importing the effects module: `import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';`

Comment: I'm in the same boat TomP - trying to learn ngrx and keep hitting snags.  The examples show that "ofType" should be exported from "@ngrx/effects" but I'm not seeing it either.

Comment: @Z.Bagley ofc i imported module to app.module.ts ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at [@ngrx/effects API](https://github.com/ngrx/effects/blob/5afd01a07968d59c5c54d8af91ce0faa0abde8fa/docs/api.md), there's no sign that this library has implemented a lettable version of `ofType`, so your second implementation won't work (at least not with `ofType` inside the pipe).

Your first implementation is just missing an import for `mergeMap`

```js
import 'rxjs/add/observable/mergeMap';
```

and probably `map` and `catch` as well

```js
import 'rxjs/add/observable/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/catch';
```

If you want to use `ofType` with `pipe`, this will probably work

```js
@Effect()
getWifiData: Observable<Action> = 
  this.actions$.ofType(WifiTypes.getWifiNetworks)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((action: GetWifiNetworks) =>
      ...
```

since `ofType()` returns an Observable which has `.pipe` already added to it's prototype.

---

**Footnote**

After looking through the source code on github (as at 22 Jan 2018), I found an export for lettable `ofType` here [platform/modules/effects/src/index.ts](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/effects/src/index.ts).

But upon installing with `@ngrx/effects@latest` (which gives me ver 4.1.1) I can't see this export reference under the installed node_modules folder.

In my component, I can't use `import { ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';` either.

Comment: I was following https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/example-app/app/auth/effects/auth.effects.ts

Comment: Looks like a work-in-progress, see at the top `brandonroberts chore(Example): Refactor example app to use lettable operators`

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that's correct just from the comment - but your test indicates it.

Comment: It's not just in that one example-app, i'ts all over the docs - https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/README.md

Comment: And yarn reports the release date as `'4.1.1': '2017-11-07T22:56:01.612Z'`

Comment: Deleted my previous comments, as I found an export for lettable `ofType` here [platform/modules/effects/src/index.ts](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/effects/src/index.ts)

Comment: @RichardMatsen so how should import looks like ?

Comment: Is this for the 1st or 2nd implementation?

Comment: well for export in `platform/modules/effects/src/index.ts ` and btw ... imports like `import { map, mergeMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';` for `rxjs v5.5.x` works fine

Comment: LOL I was just asking @Tucker that. See the issue report he found, the standard npm install doesn't give us lettable 'ofType'. Maybe tomorrow it will!

Comment: In the meantime, my code samples should work for you.

Comment: we are dealing with some serious "fresh" code here :D

Comment: Indeed. Since the nightly install gave ver 5.0.0-alpha.0, I wonder if the lettable operator was meant for the next major release, and unfortunately the documenters jumped the gun.

Comment: It's now available in 5.2.0. Use: `import { Effect, Actions, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the docs are reflecting a nightly release.

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/727

Nightly release is available here: https://github.com/ngrx/effects-builds

Comment: Any idea of the npm synatx to get that nightly build? Or do we just download the zip and park it in node_modules?

Comment: According to https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/v4.1.1/docs/effects it should be:npm install @ngrx/effects --save OR yarn add @ngrx/effects

However I wasn't able to get it to work with npm.

Comment: Mmm, so I just did `yarn add github:ngrx/effects-builds` but still no joy trying to import it.

Comment: Also, the version installed is now `5.0.0-alpha.0` which is a bit scary. (And requires same version for @ngrx/store).